# SQL query to join 2 tables and find the matching rows based on a criteria

Tags: sql

Suppose I'm trying to construct a SQL query to find all people that haven't made a sale since 6/1/2012 and I have 2 tables:

```
UserID    FirstName    LastName
1000      Ted          Ting
1001      Sally        Song
1002      Adam         Apple

UserID   SalesDate
1000     8/1/2012
1000     6/12/2012
1000     6/11/2012
1000     5/3/2012
1001     3/1/2012
1001     5/30/2012
1002     6/15/2012
1002     5/1/2011
```

The result of this query would contain columns:

```
UserID   FirstName   LastName  LastSalesDate
1001     Sally       Song      5/30/2012
```

Notice that this just returns Sally's latest sale, not all sales that were before the date (it doesn't show the sale on 3/1/2012).  What is the right SQL query to get this?

Comment: What database platform?  There's ways to do this in ANSI SQL, and there's way's to do it in vendor-specific SQL.  Vendor-specific syntax is usually cleaner.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth: MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.UserID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName, MAX(SalesDate) AS SalesDate
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t1 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserID
GROUP BY t1.UserID, t1.FirstName, t1.LastName
HAVING MAX(SalesDate) < '20120601'
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to do an inner join on the table based on the userid.  then you can use where to filter on the date you have defined.

```
select top 1 * from table1 as t1 
  inner join table2 as t2 on t2.userid = t1.userid 
  where t2.lastsalesdate < '6/1/2012' order by t2.lastsalesdate desc;
```

Comment: This won't work. It returns all sales before 6/1/2012, not just the most recent.

Comment: @TMC updated based on your comments.  not for sure you want to -1 people who are trying to help you.

Comment: Kyle: This returns only a single row, not all the rows that would match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.userid,t.firstname,t.lastname,max(t1.salesdate) as lastsalesdate 
from table1 as t1 
left outer join table2 as t2 on t2.userid = t1.userid 
where t1.userid not in(select t3.userid from table2 where t3.lastsalesdate < '6/1/2012')
group by t2.userid;
```

Comment: This syntax seems wrong in a few places. For example `...select t3.userid from table2...`. `t3` isn't declared anywhere. Also, even if you correct this, it throws error about t.firstname not being in the aggregate function or group by clause.